# Reading multiple RGB images to numpy array

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I want to read multiple RGB images to a numpy array. All my images are of resolution (32,32,3). I have 10 images in the folder and I want my final "images" numpy array as (10, 32, 32, 3). I tried below code.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os

folder = 'test_images'
images = np.array([(mpimg.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))) for filename in os.listdir('test_images')], dtype='uint8')
```

I get below error

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-0c5d51212e48> in <module>()
      3 
      4 folder = 'test_images'
----> 5 images = np.array([(mpimg.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))) for filename in os.listdir('test_images')], dtype='uint8')
      6 
      7 print(len(images))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,32,3) into shape (32,32)
```

Comment: do you mean the resulting shape should be (10, 32, 32, 3) or really (10, 32, 32, 5)? if the second, then why 5 channels?

Comment: @BloodyD It was my mistake it should be (10, 32, 32, 3). I have corrected it

Comment: One thing could be, that some of the images are loaded as grayscale images. Try using PIL to load the image and convert it to RGB: np.asarray(Image.open(imname).convert("RGB"))

Comment: @BloodyD I changed image reading library to cv2 and PIL as you suggested. It works fine, probably some issue with structure returned by this library

Comment: yes, I think matplotlib reads some metadata of the image to determine whether to load the image as grayscale or RGB. It helps sometime if you definitely know, that your images are all RGB, but in this case, as you see, some manual reading and conversion is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize the solution, I would do the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, numpy as np
folder = 'test_images'

read = lambda imname: np.asarray(Image.open(imname).convert("RGB"))

ims = [read(os.path.join(folder, filename)) for filename in os.listdir(folder)]
im_array = np.array(ims, dtype='uint8')
```